# Optaplanner - local phase 0 step in total in 1 minute

Tags: optaplanner

I have set up a solver with two local search phases and it works fine. However, there was a time that the 2nd phase didn't make any move in about 1 minute, as the log shows below:

```
...

2016-05-07 14:14:55,847 [main] DEBUG     LS step (10069), time spent (593822), score (0hard/-81medium/5395020soft),     best score (0hard/-80medium/5393781soft), accepted/selected move count (5/48), picked move (CL [cID=1147576, id=27246 => SL [id=49, sID=E942648]] <=> CL [cID=1133912, id=14716 => SL [ id=7, sID=E942592]]).

2016-05-07 14:14:55,858 [main] DEBUG     LS step (10070), time spent (593833), score (0hard/-81medium/5395390soft),     best score (0hard/-80medium/5393781soft), accepted/selected move count (5/18), picked move (CL [cID=1142322, id=22533 => SL [ id=51, sID=E943251]] <=> CL [cID=1134362, id=14118 => SL [ id=49, sID=E942648]]).

2016-05-07 14:14:55,858 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (10071), time spent (593833), best score (0hard/-80medium/5393781soft).

2016-05-07 14:16:05,042 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (2) ended: step total (0), time spent (663017), best score (0hard/-80medium/5393781soft).

2016-05-07 14:16:05,042 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (663017), best score (0hard/-80medium/5393781soft), average calculate count per second (2771).
```

Before phase 1 ended, there wasn't any improvement in the last couple of steps. And phase 2 started but made 0 step in a minute. The solver then ended because it has reached the maximum time allowed.

I'm a bit surprised that phase 2 made no step at all. Is it simply because it didn't manage to find any better score?

Comment: I think it's just because there wasn't any better move found - if I set the logging level to Trace I should be able to see the moves.

Comment: What's your solver configuration? 2 Local Search phases is supported, but not common.

Comment: Re. the number of local search phases - I thought there is no limit for it?

Comment: there is no limit for it - it's just rare to use multiple, but there are definitely good use cases for it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see any moves in TRACE log (as suggested in comments), it could be because you're using a custom move list factory and that's taken too long to initialize.

Comment: Yes I do have 2 local search phases. Both use the same custom valueSelector, entitySelector and swapMoveSelector, but with different acceptors and foragers. And I am not using any custom move list factory.

The selectors are pretty straight forward and there should be no delay at all.

The only place I suspect is the acceptor of 2nd local search uses Tabu Search of size 100. I am doing some benchmarking to find out whether the configuration is still good.

Comment: Trace logging indeed will explain what's going on.

Comment: Got an issue with logging after I upgraded it to 6.4.0 Final from 6.3.0 Final. The logging outputs in the IDE console became:

`2016-05-18 23:22:33,045 [main] DEBUG State was INACTIVE is nw FIRING_ALL_RULES
2016-05-18 23:22:33,047 [main] DEBUG Fire Loop
2016-05-18 23:22:34,464 [main] DEBUG Fire Loop
`
....

I read the upgrade recipe and there seems nothing about the change in logging.

Comment: That looks like drools TRACE output. In logback.xml (or log4j.xml) put the category org.drools to WARN and the category org.optaplanner to TRACE.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. Yes this fixes the issue by adding org.drools to WARN in the logback.xml.

Comment: If you mean why there was 0 step in the second local search phase, I suspect it's related to the configuration of the algorithm and I am doing benchmarks now. Probably would be able to find out more later.